# javascript not working on IE10 / No errors. Works fine on other normal browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
var depth = 0;
var moving = false;
var answers = new Array();
var qNo = 0;
var rangeCarousel;
var productCarousel;
var ih, iw, orient;
var sidebarOpen = false;
var focused = "range";
var currentRange = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    document.getElementById('intro').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    document.getElementById('q1').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    document.getElementById('q2').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    document.getElementById('q3').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    document.getElementById('q4').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

    document.getElementById('intro').addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', transitionEnd);
    document.getElementById('intro').addEventListener('transitionend', transitionEnd);
    document.getElementById('intro').addEventListener('transition', transitionEnd);

});

function clickHandler(e) {
    if ((qNo < 4) && (e.target.id != 'intro')) {
        qNo++;

        if (!moving) {
            depth -= 100;
            document.getElementById('intro').style.top = (depth + '%');
            document.getElementById('q1').style.top = (depth + '%');
            document.getElementById('q2').style.top = (depth + '%');
            document.getElementById('q3').style.top = (depth + '%');
            document.getElementById('q4').style.top = (depth + '%');
            moving = true;
        }

    } else if (qNo == 4) {

        var c = e.target.parentNode.classList[0];
        switch (c) {
        case 'one':
            window.open("test.html","_self");
            break;
        case 'two':
            window.open("test.html","_self");
            break;
        case 'three':
            window.open("test.html","_self");
            break;
        case 'four':
            window.open("test.html","_self");
            break;
        }
    }

}

function transitionEnd() {
    moving = false;
}
```

i m trying to create a quiz where users clicks on the images then loads the answer. It works fine on ie11 but i also need to make it work on ie10. I cant see any errors or anything to show me whats wrong

Any help or suggestion will be great

Comment: My guess: Error would be in `e.target.parentNode.classList[0]`. If you've jQuery loaded, why not use it.

Comment: sorry Tushar , im not that great with js can you be more specific ?

Comment: For example, the code inside ready can be written as `$('#intro, #q1, #q2, #q3, #q4').click(clickHandler); $('#intro').on('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend transition', transitionEnd);` That's it.

Comment: And to get parent, use `.parent()`, to get classnames `.attr('class')`

Comment: @Tushar or better, `.hasClass()`

Answer (score 1):

Some old IE does not support `target` property. You can use `e.srcElement` which is an alias of `target` as an alias of target

```
((e.target || e.srcElement).id) === "intro"
```

& also use it to find the `parentNode`

**Side Note** :As mentioned in comment section you can use `jquery` as which will also reduce the number of lines in your code beside efficiently handling `events`

You can also use [jquery multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) instead of writing same lines of code for attaching event to every selector.

```
$('sel1 ,selector2 , selector 3 ...').click(function(event){.. rest of code})
```

Comment: @Tushar Right!!. It was typo  I have edited & fixed it

Comment: Thanks Guys weirdly it loads intro div